# Why Nginx sends requests to upstream servers sequentially

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use Nginx as Load Balancer with the following config:

```
http {
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8010;
    server 127.0.0.1:8011;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
}
```

So I have 2 local servers which are Flask apps:

```
#app1.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response
import time

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def root():
    time.sleep(5)
    return jsonify({"response": "Hello, world!"})

app.run(debug=False, port=8010) # for app2.py the only diff is port=8011
```

When I do 4 calls simultaneously (in different tabs) `localhost:80`, then I need to wait for 20 seconds to see "Hello, world!" in all 4 tabs (instead of 10 as I expected, because it should be distributed to 2 servers, for each it should take 10 seconds, but instead it just processes it sequentially one-by-one). Can you explain why? And how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with it a bit more and realized that this behavior is only reproducible, when I open several tabs in Chromium. For my other browser (Firefox) everything works as expected. Also, if I do `curl` requests, everything works as expected as well.